# Seeing a positive trend line on chart with Negative R^2. How can the trend be positive, but the correlation negative?

Tags: probability, statistics, linear-regression

[image]

Hi! I have the data and scatterplot as shown. I fit a line to it.

The fit line looks positive and yields a function of:

y=0.125715x+(84.663831)

However, when I calculate the r squared I get -29.3.
This is true if I calculate by hand or using a function.

How do I interpret this result? I agree that the chart looks noisey enough to not have a strong r squared, but the strong trend line is still there.

Is it possible this is a polynomial distribution and my r2 is not fit for this?

Comment: Simple linear regression does not produce a negative $R^2$ (it must be in $[0,1]$).  So you are doing something else which your statistics are reporting as much worse in a mean-square residual sense than simply predicting the average value of the response variable.

Comment: You can get negative r-square values, as it compares your equation to the null hypothesis (flat line)

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan - only if your equation increases the squares of the residuals compared to a horizontal line through the mean. Simple linear regression does not do that: it minimises the squares of the residuals.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a mistake in my use of the function. I was not using the model's predicted output, and instead reusing the initial data!